# Change the direction of printing my file

Tags: c#, .net, printing

As I press the button, my program prints the `.html` file, but prints the wrong way. It cuts my file and I want it to print vertically. What can I add to the code to change it? (it always has to print vertically)

```
WebBrowser myWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    myWebBrowser.DocumentText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\BACard.html");
}

private void myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myWebBrowser.Print();
}
```

Comment: You are going to read a lot to get this working. The Webbrowser controller uses IE, and therefore you should check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753280(v=vs.85).  Consider using Chromium (https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser). Also interesting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's observing your printer settings, as it should. If you want to set the print to a value other than your printer's current orientation, margins, etc., use [ShowPageSetupDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.showpagesetupdialog(v=vs.110).aspx), and to see a preview, use [ShowPrintPreviewDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.showprintpreviewdialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 private void myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        myWebBrowser.ShowPageSetupDialog();
        //OR
        myWebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    }
```

These display IE-style dialogs per their associated pages, which (IIRC) allow you to print from the dialog.